# How do you know when to just down-vote vs. when to close (or both)?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, downvotes

I tend to move between the [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery), and [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tags, so perhaps this is more of an indictment than anything else:

I'll use this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236215/select-php-sending-variable-to-a-web-service-retrieve-the-answer-in-the-same) (EDIT: it has now been updated with code) as an example - should it be down-voted, close voted or both?

The reason that I ask is because I can run through these tags first thing each day and be out of votes rapidly, leaving no votes for me to give when other questions like this start to come up during the remainder of the day. I was considering extending that by down-voting (without close voting) some and the inverse on others. I have been fiercely and somewhat nauseatingly adding stock 'how to ask' comments on as many as I can catch hoping to stem the tide of bad questions on these. I have sparingly used flags unless I have run out of votes and the question is egregiously bad.

Many of these questions never receive enough close votes, perhaps because some are avoiding down-voted questions thinking, "that's been down-voted, so I won't even go look". Many times these questions move off of the front page of a given tag very quickly, forever lost to the ether of the Internet.

Comment: Once a single close vote has been cast, these questions will not escape the CV review queue forever, though.

Comment: @Patrick, indeed, but only if the question has been viewed 100 times or more. By then, if the question actually needs to be closed, other votes should have piled up (luckily).

Comment: When I scan through questions and see one that has been downvoted, I look at it even if I would otherwise have not looked at it, to see if it should be closed. I'm probably in the minority though, and I can't guarantee that I'll always do this.

Answer (score 5):

Downvote:

- When the question does not show research effort (Here's my assignment, fix it.)
- Question is unclear (I have query on same, How Do I Make Codes Work On New Server?)
- Question is not useful (Why do IDEs suck?)

Vote to close:

- Question is a duplicate
- It's unclear what the user is asking
- It contains code, and does not have the criteria needed to resolve the issue (code that reproduces issue, clear problem statement, desired behavior, inputs, outputs)
- It's too broad (How do I create an HTTP Server in C#?)
- It's not about programming (it could be sys administration, about general software, or just about bananas)

There is a little overlap there (especially in the unclear side), but you can have a question that meets all of the criteria to be open and still be a bad question. That's when you downvote.

The important thing is to not manufacture a reason to close just because you don't want to downvote. It sends a mixed signal to the question asker and to the rest of the community.

Comment: `The important thing is to not manufacture a reason to close just because you don't want to downvote. It sends a mixed signal to the question asker and to the rest of the community.` - this is the curse of the custom close reason.  The custom reason is needed to help provide specific guidance but is very prone to abuse.

Comment: @psub, *this comment appears to be off-topic because it uses code formatting for quoting and confuses dashes and hyphens* ;p

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi `What` do `you` mean - `???` I `thought` you `were` supposed to `highlight` irrelavant `stuff` with these funny `quotes`

Comment: @psub, I just lost 20% sight on both eyes ;)